# Where can I ask a question about a tech-specific term?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask if there is a technical antonym of "portable", in reference to portable apps¹, but I'm unsure which site to post on:

- It's about technical computer terminology, not colloquial or necessarily otherwise common usage. Thus, I thought Super User might be more appropriate since it would likely have a greater chance of containing someone who would know the answer.
- It's still about usage of the English language, though, so maybe EL&U would still be the most appropriate.

Advice?

---

¹ Please note that I'm referring to programs that are portable, **not** [PortableApps.com](http://www.portableapps.com).

Comment: I'd go with ELU.  I'm not a member of either community (and I haven't read their on-topic pages), so I can't really say for sure.

Comment: Thank you. :) And yes, I shall verify by posting on EL&U Meta first.

Comment: Also, wouldn't your comment be more appropriate as an answer?

Comment: I'm not confident in it, and I don't want to spend the time to provide reasons why my answer is correct (like confirming what is on-topic).  Otherwise, yeah I'd post an answer instead.

Comment: Personally as a SU mod - I dislike terminology questions since they kinda straddle the 'too broad','primarily opinion based' and 'not solving any practical problem' reasons for not being a real question.